# Laravel - Vue - Components not updating

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js, components

I have a fresh installation of laravel 5.4.

I have successfully created a new component and displayed it correctly.

I use `npm run watch` and my .vue files get compiled correctly.

But now, any changes I make to **the .vue files do not get updated**.

I purposely made errors to them to see if they compiled but they failed, so I conclude that the watch command successfuly sees changes made to them, on the other hand, nothing updates in the browser (only blade files update).

Any ideas what this could come from ?

PS: I tried `php artisan cache:clear` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Silly, the name of the component had a dash in it:

```
Vue.component('cardtest-component', require('./components/CardTestComponent.vue'));
```

It was just a typo.

Comment: So it was typo ?

Comment: Yes, it was. Silly question sorry :)